# DirectX redistributable package breakdown

Tags: directx

Am I allowed to redistribute only parts of the DirectX package? (e.g. only the DirectDraw DLLs, without Show/3D/etc.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. From the DirectX SDK Redist EULA:

> ### DirectX Software Development Kit Redistributable Code
>
> Redistributable Code is identified as
>   all of the files in the following 
>   "Redist" directory on the DirectX SDK
>   CD/Download:
>
> redist/
>
> The following files in the above
>   directory must be included in any
>   distribution of  the DirectX Runtime.
>
> DSetup32.dll 
>   DSetup.dll 
>   DXSetup.exe
>   DXupdate.cab
>   dxdllreg_x86.cab

Comment: a EULA is an END-USER license. Where can one find the developer license?

Comment: Yes. The DirectX SDK EULA is the EULA for END-USERS of the SDK.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is "yes" and "no" depending on what eaxctly you are asking about. You are not able to ship any of the 'raw' DLLs in your app from the DirectX SDK, and you must make use of DirectSetup. You can, however, include only the CABs you actually need as discussed on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee416805.aspx#small_installation_packages).

This really only applies to the DirectX SDK optional side-by-side components such as D3DX, XAudio2, etc. As discussed in [Not So DirectSetup](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2010/09/08/not-so-direct-setup.aspx), DirectDraw is actually part of the Windows operating system. You don't update it with a REDIST starting with DirectX 9.0c which is included with Windows XP Service Pack 2, Windows Server 2003 Service Pack 1, and Windows XP x64 Edition. DirectDraw is *always* there. What you do instead is just set a [you must be this high to ride-this-ride](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2010/02/24/what-s-in-a-version-number.aspx) OS version check and assume it's already installed because it is. This is simply a function of setting your minimum supported OS version correctly.