# Condition to Install DirectX End-User Runtime

Tags: directx, installshield, prerequisites

I'm using InstallShield 2013 (Basic MSI Project) to create installation package for my product.
Product requires DirectX End-User-Runtime to be installed, so I created custom prerequisite for DirectX in my InstallShield solution.

I don't want install DirectX End-User-Runtime every time I install my product, so I want to add a condition for DirectX in Prerequisite Editor. My product is a 64-bit application and it requires some directX files in C:\Windows\System32 folder (At least I know that it won't work without D3DCompiler_43.dll and D3DX9_43.dll).

So, I'm adding conditions for my prerequisite:

Install DirectX End-User-Runtime if files 
**[WindowsFolder]system32\D3DCompiler_43.dll** and 
**[WindowsFolder]system32\D3DX9_43.dll**
are missed on target box.

I tested my installation package on two 64-bit Win7 boxes. DirectX Prerequisite condition works fine on the first box - it installs DirectX only if both D3DCompiler_43.dll and D3DX9_43.dll are missed in C:\Windows\System32. But problem appears when I install the same package on the second 64-bit box: for some reasons prerequisite condition doesn't work properly there - it tries to find D3DCompiler_43.dll and D3DX9_43.dll not in C:Windows\System32 but in C:Windows\SysWOW64 folder.
Can someone explain why it looks in SysWOW64 even if I hardcode path to C:\Windows\System32?

And one more question - probably someone knows a better way how to check if DirectX End-User-Runtime is installed on target box? I found similar topic here [check registry for DirectX End-User Runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11627013/check-registry-for-directx-end-user-runtime), but I cannot understand how and where in Prerequisite Editor can I use LoadLibrary("d3dx9_43.dll") function...

Comment: I would guess that redirecting a hard-coded System32 path is due to app compat.  Until 64-bit was available, apps could hard-code the System32 path and work just fine.  On a 64-bit system, however, they would be pointing to the wrong directory.  Redirecting to SysWOW64 fixes it.

Answer (score 0):

In InstallShield 2013, there are 2 types of prerequisites:
 - *Setup Prerequisites* install before the main install
 - *Feature Prerequisites* install only if that feature is selected for
   installation.

You can't call a DLL in a *Setup Prerequisite*, because a setup prerequisite runs before your MSI, and therefore before any of your custom actions.

If you create a *Feature Prerequisite*, you can set a custom action to call a DLL (such as d3dx9_43.dll that you mentioned). I am not familiar with this DLL, so I can't tell you what your custom action would look like. You can turn on or off this feature based on the result of your DLL call.